# Router is assigning Class A and class C IP address

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

The router in our office is assigning 192.168.1.x , and 10.x.x.x IP addresses automatically. How do i standardize it's assigning of ip addresses as 10.x.x.x? The workstations in our office is set to obtain ip address automatically.

Comment: 1. Off-topic for this here *programming* site. 2. This'll need a lot more details to actually answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually routers provide an HTML interface for a connected device to login. Here it might be 192.168.1.0 or 10.x.x.0.

You have to login to the router, and depending upon the model of the router, you can configure the ip address range for the network.